# How to run commads from Spring boot webapp

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, maven, command-line

I have Spring boot web application where I want to call some commands in command line. When I use ProcessBuilder and Process class after I run the process, ExecutorService is shut down.

Method where I run the process:

```
public void runTestsInProject(String projectPath){
    System.out.println("Starting runTestsInProject() ------");
    try{
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"" + projectPath + "\" && mvn clean test");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process p = builder.start();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Error log:

```
2020-07-27 20:33:20.246  INFO 7248 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-27 20:33:20.250  INFO 7248 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-07-27 20:33:20.254  INFO 7248 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-07-27 20:33:20.270  INFO 7248 --- [       Thread-4] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Spring starts again ...

```
2020-07-27 20:33:29.778  INFO 7248 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have added **spring-boot-devtools** in your dependencies. Devtools restarts the application whenever it finds a change in the classpath of the project.

The process you are running(**mvn-clean**) is causing a change in the classpath of the project and hence your application is restarting.

If you run ordinary processes that don't interfere with the project's classpath, you will not face the restart or executor shutdown problem.

Look at this snapshot from [spring dev tools documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html):

`As DevTools monitors classpath resources, the only way to trigger a restart is to update the classpath. The way in which you cause the classpath to be updated depends on the IDE that you are using. In Eclipse, saving a modified file will cause the classpath to be updated and trigger a restart. In IntelliJ IDEA, building the project (Build -> Build Project) will have the same effect`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that when I run my project in my IDE, Maven is involved and because the command that I try to call from my application runs different Maven operation, so it shuts down my application to perform the command. When I build the project and run the app from jar file then the application keeps running. Now I have a different problem that the command I want to run from webapp doesn't run Maven operation in specified path, but in the directory where the webapp is.

Comment: You should remove the "cmd.exe \c" prefix as it is meant to run the command ("cd") in a separate cmd interpreter.  The following should run fine:
 new ProcessBuilder ("cd \"" + projectPath + "\" && mvn clean test") ;

Answer (score 0):

**1)** First problem is in command

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
                "cmd.exe", "/c", "c: && cd \"" + projectPath + "\" && mvn clean test");
```

instead of

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"" + projectPath + "\" && mvn clean test");
```

Windows cmd propably is not always at the same starting point, so when cmd is started and points on D: disc and your command si for example cd C:\smt\doc is pointing then it doesnt work. So it needs to be sayed on which disc to operate at the beginning of the command.

**2)** Second problem could be that maven used by IDE to build and run the application is being shut down by maven command that I make by ProcessBuilder. So the solution is to build the application jar file and run it from cmd.